# Break and wrap word when it's too lengthy

Tags: jsp

I have to iterate names and display on a JSP page. It is displaying properly. But if the name is too large like more than 100 character then appearance get change i.e. it is going out of the page.

Example:

```
Names:

aaaa

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

I want to display like below result.

```
Names:

aaaa

aaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

I want it to be fit in specified area. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose the name in a div with the following CSS style:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

See http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/word-wrap-force-text-to-wrap for a demo